# how to make the php vars untouched when generating view in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I try to generate new blade files from the controller.
So how it works.
I take the main blade file and try to inject the data from the contentbuilder. The data from the contentbuilder is correct like i want it but all the `{{$vars}}` from the main file are converted in strings instead of `{{$vars}}`.
for example :

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Becomes :

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="T4JB7Y1DNdIXsWe4k0AiLUaKtSvoDJwIcSOgGW5e">
```

How can i avoid this ?

i've tried with `->render()` but its the same results.
i've tried with includes but same result.

This is how the new blade file is generated.

```
$page = PagesDetails::where('uuid',$request->page)->first();

File::put(resource_path('views/front/demotest.blade.php'),
        view('front.defaultpage',["pagecontent" => $request->item,"settings" => $this->settings,"page"=> $page])
```

I just want to phpvars untouched so it can be called automatically when page loads.

so that the `{{$vars}}` stays in the new generated blade file

How i fixed this :
Because all the help here was not completely how i wanted it, i did some modification by myself.

First the data (received from the contentbuilder) was saved to a new blade file.
Then i did a prepend file to add the first part of the default blade file with all the php vars.
Then i did an append file to add the last part of the default blade file.
So after that i had a complete blade file like i wrote it manually with working php vars.

Comment: Try with `value="{!! '{{ csrf_token() }}' !!}"`.

Comment: This does the trick !!!  Thank you !!!

Comment: @Tpojka and how can i fix it for such vars : {!! SEO::generate() !!}

Comment: Put quotes around. I wrote answer bellow.

Comment: You have to put it in curly braces as much as you expected to see once: `{!! '{{ SEO::generate() }}' !!}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next syntax:

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{!! '{{ csrf_token() }}' !!}">
```

Explanation:

```
{!! 'something' !!}
```

When you use this syntax variable won't evaluate but rather parsed as is.
Then you need to place string representation of what you want to be there. Therefor quotes over function/helper.

Read about "Displaying Unescaped Data" in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade).

Comment: its working for everything except for vars like this : {!! SEO::generate() !!}
BTW this is the default var (untouched)

Comment: Compare again what you wrote and what I wrote. You missed two pairs of curly braces. Read what is written under "Use next syntax:".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can preserve only the vars, but you can get the raw content of the view file using plain PHP, for example:

```
file_get_contents(resource_path('views/home.blade.php'));
```

Comment: i will try i want the complete blade file untouched so it could work with this